# Codeigniter Page Not Found - Migrating To Live Server

Tags: codeigniter

I was uploading my code based on CI to a live website and it keeps getting error 404.

The web structure is like this :

```
web
  -Application
  -Assets
  -Cache
  -..so on
index.php
```

Here's my Application/Config/Routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'H';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

This is my H controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class H extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(empty($this->session->userdata("userData")['id'])) redirect('/login');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        if(isset($_GET['guid'])){
            $data['post'] = getListPost($_GET['guid']);
        }else{
            $data['post'] = getStickyPost();
        }
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
        $this->load->view('partials/sidebar-home');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }
    public function materi()
    {
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('management/post/lists');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }
}
```

And this is my Login Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function index($slug="")
    {
        if(isset($_POST['username'])){
            $cek = $this->checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
            if($cek){
                $newdata = array("userData"=>array(
                    'name'  => $cek[0]['nama'],
                    'id'  => $cek[0]['id'],
                    'nip'  => $cek[0]['nip'],
                    'jabatan'  => $cek[0]['jabatan'],
                    'unit_kerja'  => $cek[0]['unit_kerja'],
                    'foto'  => $cek[0]['foto'],
                    'hak_akses'  => ($cek[0]['hak_akses_knowledge_management']=="")?"pengguna":$cek[0]['hak_akses_knowledge_management'],
                    'unit_kerja_atasan'  => $cek[0]['unit_kerja_atasan'],
                    'email'     => $_POST['username'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE));

                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                redirect('/');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_status','false'); 
                redirect('/login');
            }   
        }
        // $this->load->view('partials/header');
        // $this->load->view('partials/login');
        // $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        $this->load->view('partials/single_login');
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/');
    }

    public function newlogin(){
        $this->load->view('partials/single_login');
    }

    function checkLogin($email,$password){
        $this->db->where("nip",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);
        $query  = $this->db->get("data_pegawai"); 
        return $query->result_array();

    }

}
```

When I change the routes to default it works, somehow when i return to 'H' it keeps getting error 404.

This is the structure of views folder :

```
management
    infografis
    post
    ebook
partials
    header.php
    single_login.php
    footer.php
    sidebar-home.php
    login.php
category
    infografis.php
    ebook.php
errors
home.php
post.php
welcome_message.php
```

Comment: AFAIR, Controller names are strictly case sensitive: filenames must begin with an uppercase and so do the names in the code (so `H.php` and `class H extends...`) are correct but the name in the `$route['default_controller']` directive should be lowercase. Try `$route['default_controller'] = 'h';`

Comment: As @JavierLarroulet pointed routes should be lowercase, they basically should have the same structure as your url. Your controllers are always lowercase in your url. Also I think its pretty weird to have a controller named with just one letter. But that might be just me.

Comment: Dear JavierLarroulet and marccogmonteiro thank you for your response, i've already replace the case. Unfortunately it still shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are expected to be lowecase, even if Controller file names and class names begin with an uppercase character.

So, `H.php`, `class H extends CI_Controller` are correctly capitalized. However, `$route['default_controller']` should be assigned a lowercase value.

Try using
`$route['default_controller'] = 'h';` instead of `'H'` and you should be up and running

Comment: thanks javier, i've changed the case, it still gives me 404.

Comment: What about your server (apache or nginx?) configuration? does it match the one on your development server?